# Passing form values from javascript to wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I know I can take post data from WordPress / PHP and pass it into JS by using AJAX. But is it possible to do this the other way round? i.e. create a JS event listener on a form and the pass the values back to the server to be executed using a PHP function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definietly. You pretty much answerd the question yourself.Here is some code to get you started.

```
document.querySelector(".whateverFormSubmit").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let formInfo = document.querySelector("input1");
  let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.querySelector("response").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "ajax.php", true);
  xhttp.send('formInfo=' + formInfo);
})
```

Pay attention to preventDefault(), if you don't use it your form will be posted through HTTP body, thus rendering your AJAX useless.

And there you go, you posted information from frontend to backend without refreshing the page. Of course you can mess around with sending a JSON, but I kept it simple.